# Using Angular Directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i'm learning how to use Angular Directives to manipulate my HTML. And i have some doubts about it.

I have my hideElementDirective:

```
var hideElementDirective = function() {

    var hideElement = {
        init: function(element) {
            element.css('display', 'none');
        }
    }

    return {
        link: function($scope, $element) {
            hideElement.init($element);
        }
    }
}

angular.module('app').directive('hideElementDirective', hideElementDirective);
```

Call in the HTML:

```
<hide-element-directive> This tag will disappear </hide-element-directive>
```

Everything perfect.

Lets increase the logic. I have this indicator that will toggle the state of the hide-element-directive, how should i name the indicator, and how should i catch in the directive?

Example:

```
<hide-element-directive> This tag will hide/show if you click in the indicator element that </hide-element-directive>
```

indicator element: `<button> If you click me i will hide/show the hide-element-directive </button>`

There is any convetion for that? Should i use data-* or insert a class name related like `class="hide-element-directive-indicator"`

Thanks.

Comment: you can `transclude` the element you want to hide and use a template in directive defenition for making a button as an indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to interact with parent directive is through its controller, via `require`. This way you aren't attached to its scope and can talk to 'through' nested directives that may have their own scopes.

So, two directives are required for that.

```
app.directive('hidee', function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    controller: function ($scope) {
      this.hide = function () {
        $scope.hidden = true;
      }
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('hidden', function (newVal) {
        newVal && element.css('display', 'none');
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive('hider', function () {
  return {
    require: '^hidee',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, hideeCtrl) {
      element.on('click', function () {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          hideeCtrl.hide();
        });
      })
    }
  };
});
```

`hidee` can live without `hider`, but not vice versa. And the usage is

```
<hidee>Hide me with <button hider>hider</button></hidee>
```

And it will work even with

```
<hidee>Hide me 
    <isolate-scope-dir>with <button hider>hider</button></isolate-scope-dir>
</hidee>
```

Regarding conventions, it is a good habit to stick to element/attribute directives (hence the default `restrict: 'EA'` for directives). And in case of `button` `hider`` attribute is preferable to element because of button appearance.

I guess that the question is about generic directive interaction and not recreating ngShow/ngHide functionality, so I deliberately don't mention them.

Comment: That's exactly what is searching for. Thanks.

Comment: yeap, you are right, this is not about ngShow/ngHide, i used a generic example for describe what i was trying to understand.

Comment: @estus Very nice example, but I think you could simplify it a little bit and just inject `$element` in `controller: function ($scope, $element)`. Having access to it, you could get rid of the `$watch`.

Comment: @mrak That's right. `$watch` is unnecessary there for simple toggling but gives a better perspective. I'm sticking to the convention where `controller` prepares the scope for linking and defines the methods for `require`, while `link` does all DOM-related stuff and interacts with `require`d controllers. It does better job for me in the end than just using either controller or link randomly.

Answer (score 2):

To address your question of naming conventions:

I don't think that there are any established conventions for this situation in particular. There isn't a convention to use `data-*`. But as always, be sure to follow the [best practices](http://www.itiseezee.com/?p=83) of naming in general!

---

I wouldn't use a directive at all; I would use `ngShow`:

VIEW

```
<div ng-show='visible'>Starts off hidden</div>
<button ng-click='toggleVisibility()'>Toggle visibility</button>
```

CONTROLLER

```
function controller($scope) {
  $scope.visible = false;
  $scope.toggleVisibility = function() {
    $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
  };
}
```

Comment: ..., which technically is a directive ;) but yes you're right. don't re-invent the wheel

Comment: well, in Front End Masters i learn that controller is for data and directives if for manipulate elements.

Comment: This is not a question about how to do or the better way, but how naming elements that directives will manipulate and other elements related with the directive

Comment: @AmandaFerrari Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean - could you clarify?

Comment: `well, in Front End Masters i learn that controller is for data and directives if for manipulate elements.` That's sort of true, but is misleading. Yes, controllers are for data and  yes, directives are for *directly* manipulating the DOM (if that's what you want to do). But the idea of Angular is that you data-bind your stuff in the view to the data in the controller. So to be clear, they probably meant that *direct/manual/imperative* manipulation of the DOM should be done in directives, not controllers. Otherwise, just declaratively data bind your stuff in the view to the controller.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari Directives are for encapsulating functionality. You are asking how to access and manipulate an DOM element, which accidentally happened to be a directive.

Comment: More/less, i know how access and manipulate the DOM element which the directive is related, i want know how to name other elements that will help the directive according to convention